# Restrict the_post-navigation to same category?

Tags: posts, navigation

How can I restrict the post navigation to only posts from within the current category?

```
<!-- the post navigation -->
<?php
    the_post_navigation( array(
        'screen_reader_text'    => __( 'MORE EVENTS' ),
        'prev_text'             => __( 'Previous: ' ) . '%title',
        'next_text'             => __( 'Next: ' ) . '%title'
    ) );
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Customize your posts navigation to get posts in the same tag.

```
the_post_navigation( array(
            'prev_text'                  => __( 'prev chapter: %title' ),
            'next_text'                  => __( 'next chapter: %title' ),
            'in_same_term'               => true,
            'taxonomy'                   => __( 'post_tag' ),
            'screen_reader_text' => __( 'Continue Reading' ),
        ) );
```

[Source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_navigation/)